# How to get latest file-name or file from S3 bucket using event triggered lambda

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am very new to AWS services and has just a week worth of experience with serverless architecture, My requirement is to trigger an event when a new file is uploaded to a specific bucket, once the event trigger is set my Lambda should get the details of the latest file such as Name, Size, and Date of creation.

The source is uploading this file in a new folder every time and names the folder with the current date.

So far I am able to crack how to create my Lambda function and listen to the event trigger.

Here is my code.

```
import boto3
import botocore
import datetime
import logging

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    logging.info('Start function')
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    DATE = datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    BUCKET_NAME = 'monkey-banana-dev'
    KEY = '/banana/incoming/daily/{}'.format(DATE)
    logging.info('Getting file from {}'.format(KEY))
    try:
        s3.Bucket(BUCKET_NAME).download_file(KEY, 'name_of_my_file')
    except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as e:
        if e.response['Error']['Code'] == "404":
            print("The object does not exist.")
        else:
            raise
```

here since I know that it's going to be today's date hence I am using `datetime` to get the exact KEY but file-name will always be different. although I know that it's going to be a text file with .txt suffix, I am not able to get around on how to get the name of the latest uploaded file and other details from the trigger.

Comment: You can find sample data from events here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/eventsources.html#eventsources-s3-put

Comment: @T4rk1n not finding it much useful, I am very new to AWS.

Answer (score 10):

You have an [event object](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/eventsources.html#eventsources-s3-put), it contains a key "Records" that is a list.

You can filter the records for eventName 'ObjectCreated:Put' and then sort the list by key "eventTime" to get the latest event data.

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    records = [x for x in event.get('Records', []) if x.get('eventName') == 'ObjectCreated:Put']
    sorted_events = sorted(records, key=lambda e: e.get('eventTime'))
    latest_event = sorted_events[-1] if sorted_events else {}
    info = latest_event.get('s3', {})
    file_key = info.get('object', {}).get('key')
    bucket_name = info.get('bucket', {}).get('name')
```

Comment: There should be no need to sort.  There should only be one record per notification.  It's only expressed as an array because this is a standardized message format used across multiple AWS services.

Comment: Does it contain the whole file path or just the file name?

Comment: Is there a way to get filename in ECS task that runs a python script?

Answer (score 2):

As was mentioned, this link has the info - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/eventsources.html#eventsources-s3-put

What you need to do is utilize the **event** object that is passed into the function. That contains the detail that is provided in the link. As you can see in the example in the link, you need to access the **key**. This will contain the full path, including the date that you mentioned, since the key is the full file path.

To help debug this, you an always print the value of event to the console using the **print** function in Python.

Comment: For sample code that uses the S3 Event, see the Python example on [the walkthrough example](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example-deployment-pkg.html).

Answer (score 2):

'Key' will contain the whole file path.
example-

```
import boto3
import os
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket=s3.Bucket('hcss-heavyjob-raw-tables')
for key in bucket.objects.all():
    if key.key.startswith('heavyjob/EMPMAST'):
           print(key.key)'
```

Output-

> heavyjob/EMPMAST/20190524-165352044.csv
>
> heavyjob/EMPMAST/20190529-153011532.csv
>
> heavyjob/EMPMAST/LOAD00000001.csv

You can get the file name by using `basename` on `key.key`
or

```
head,tail = os.path.split(key.key)
print(tail)
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate the answer, with an example if possible?